# horizontal scroll position based callback function issue

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, next.js, react-virtualized, react-window

I am new to next , currently I am trying to implement a horizontal product list using react-window for maintaining virtualized. I wish to make api calls while scrolling and append new set of data to the product list. I have made a callback with onscroll of virtualized list but the problem is that the clientwidth and scrollwidth always remains the same and callback is done without even reaching the end of the threshold I have mentioned , also the scrollleft value always remains 0. I am struck at this point. Thanks in advance for your help.

This is the code

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import { VariableSizeList as List } from 'react-window'; // Import VariableSizeList
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Skeleton from '@mui/material/Skeleton';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Box, Stack, Typography } from '@mui/material';

import { poppinsBold } from '../../shared/appfonts';

const PAGE_SIZE = 20;
const TOTAL_PRODUCTS = 1000;
const LOAD_THRESHOLD = 200;

const HorizontalProductList = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const containerRef = useRef();

    const itemSize = (index) => 300; // Fixed width of each item in pixels

    const TitleTypography = styled(Typography)({
        fontFamily: poppinsBold.style.fontFamily,
        color: 'black',
    });

    const MediumTypography = styled(Typography)({
        fontFamily: poppinsBold.style.fontFamily,
        color: 'black',
    });

    const fetchProducts = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(
                `http://localhost:5000/products?_page=${currentPage}&_limit=${PAGE_SIZE}`
            );
            const newProducts = response.data;
            setProducts([...products, ...newProducts]);
            setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProducts();
    }, []); // Fetch initial data

    const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
        if (!isLoading && containerRef.current) {
            const container = containerRef.current;
            const isNearEnd =
                container.scrollLeft + container.clientWidth + LOAD_THRESHOLD > container.scrollWidth;
            console.log("container.scrollLeft", container.scrollLeft);
            console.log("container.clientWidth", container.clientWidth);
            console.log("container.scrollWidth", container.scrollWidth);
            console.log("isNearEnd", isNearEnd);
            if (false) {
                fetchProducts();
            }
        }
    }, [isLoading]);

    const renderSkeletonItem = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Grid item xs={1} md={2} lg={3}>
                    <Paper>
                        <Skeleton variant="rectangular" width={300} height={200} />
                        <Skeleton variant="text" width={200} />
                        <Skeleton variant="text" width={150} />
                        <Skeleton variant="text" width={80} />
                    </Paper>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    };

    const renderItem = ({ index, style }) => {
        // console.log("index", products[index])
        const product = products[index];

        if (!product) {
            // Render a skeleton loader for items that are being fetched
            return renderSkeletonItem();
        }

        return (
            <div style={style} key={product.id}>
                <Grid item xs={1} md={2} lg={3}>
                    <Paper sx={{ m: 3 }} elevation={3}>
                        <Stack display={'flex'} direction={'row'}>
                            <Image
                                width={120}
                                height={150}
                                src={
                                    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/10863290/pexels-photo-10863290.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600'
                                }
                                alt="Alternate image"
                                style={{ objectFit: 'fill' }}
                            />
                            <Box
                                display={'flex'}
                                alignItems={'center'}
                                flexDirection={'column'}
                                justifyContent={'center'}
                                width={'100%'}
                            >
                                <TitleTypography>{product.name}</TitleTypography>
                                <MediumTypography>${product.price}</MediumTypography>
                            </Box>
                        </Stack>
                    </Paper>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    };

    return (
        <div
            className="scroll-container" // Add a CSS class for horizontal scrolling
            ref={containerRef}
        >
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', overflowX: 'auto' }}>
                <List
                    height={200} // Specify the height of the list
                    width={typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.innerWidth : 0} // Check for window object
                    itemCount={products.length + PAGE_SIZE} // Use products.length + PAGE_SIZE
                    itemSize={itemSize} // Width of each item
                    layout="horizontal" // Specify horizontal layout
                    onScroll={handleScroll}
                >
                    {renderItem}
                </List>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HorizontalProductList;
```

This is the console image of the above code
[image: clientwidth and scrollwidth equals image]